# the meaning of "do damage" in baseball context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sports

What does *do damage* mean in the baseball context as in the following [excerpt](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/sports/2018/03/29/baseball/japanese-baseball/carp-loook-remain-throne-central-league-rivals-prepare-mount-challenge/) from the *Japan Times*?

> [Tanaka and Kikuchi] are a formidable combination at the top of the order, each able to **do damage** with their bats and their legs. As if that wasn’t enough, they’re all very good fielders as well.

Comment: Without more complete context it's impossible to say what is meant.

Comment: Even after Hot Licks challenge, "They are a formidable combination at the order, each able to do damgage with their bats and legs" suggests you have not paid enough attention to your Question.

“… each able to do damage with their bats and legs…” might mean much and is that all there is here?

Either way, “… a formidable combination at the order” means what, please? Would you prefer to drop that completely, or simply to withdraw the whole idea, or what?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty common to hear "damage" used nonliterally like this in sports (at least it is in the US), but unfortunately I can't find the relevant definition in any of the dictionaries I checked.

It's essentially a metaphor. The offense **attacks**, meaning:

> to move forward and try to score goals or win points
>   *Brazil began to attack more in the second half of the match.*
>   <sub>[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/Sport-topic/attack)</sub>

When their [attack](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/attack) is successful, they **do damage**, or score.

Answer (score 0):

> The objectives of the offensive team (batting team) are to hit the ball into the field of play, and to run the bases
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball), on *Baseball*

Their *bats* help by hitting such that it's hard for the other team to catch the ball quickly, and their *legs* help by running towards home base. The quote communicates that they are good at both, implying that by doing so, they help their own team win ('do damage' to the other team).