# The meaning of "popped harmlessly" in a baseball game

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sports

What does *"harmlessly"* mean in the following context?

> The unnatural silence was broken by the crack of Pujols’ bat, but the ball popped *harmlessly* into right field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the meaning of "do damage" in baseball context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/439409/the-meaning-of-do-damage-in-baseball-context)

Comment: As a Brit, I assumed that '[the ball] popped harmlessly' was merely a synonym for '[the ball] lobbed gently [with no damage to one side's or both sides' position]'. However, there seems to be a slightly narrower baseballing sense.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence means that the noise was somewhat ominous, but the actual effect -- a pop-fly out of bounds of right field -- was harmless.

Which implies, by the rules of American Baseball, that there must have been two strikes already against the batter; otherwise, the foul would have counted as a strike, and not been "harmless" at all.

Comment: 1. The quoted text says the ball popped harmlessly "into right field", not foul left. 2. The team that would be worried about the batter getting a hit would consider a strike "harmless".

Comment: 3. A *pop fly*, which is a ball that's hit high in the air but not far into the outfield, will usually be caught, putting the batter out. (which is harmless to the fielding team)

Comment: I wouldn't use "harmless" to describe something that was actually helpful, but yes, the foul territory isn't "right field" either...